# Centering YouTube Embed on Page

Tags: css, video, embed

I've been trying to center my YouTube video embed but it just won't work properly.

I've tried flexbox and center tags in html, this is the closest I've gotten, really need some help here

My Code:

**CSS**

```css
    .Video {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      transform: translate(0,-50%);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: try this: https://jsfiddle.net/6dL2zo0j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your css is wrong. Get rid of the position, display and transform. I'm pretty sure you don't need any of those.

Checkout this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/garbageacc2121/xwzdq7hj/4/) I made. I think you're looking for `margin: 0 auto;`. Make sure the embedded videos are wrapped in a div, then apply the margin. If you already have a `margin-top` or `margin-bottom`, then just set `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto;`

Comment: I got it to work now I also used `padding` element to tidy it up to my liking. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Awesome, glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

To use flex-box, this works:
Embed your `.video` in a `.flex-container`. Give this `.flex-container` a width and a height. And add the following properties to the .flex-container: `justify-content` and `align-items` set them both to `center`. Thats it. 
Check [this codepen](https://codepen.io/Sven72/pen/OJPOrro). I used joes (above) HTML markup.

Also take a look at the out-commented markup above the codepen.

It's just important that the elements you want to center are direct children of the element the flex property is applied to.